# Meaning of "XXXX halt"

Tags: expression

I had the following exchange while chatting:

[image]

I did not understand the word "Futterpampe", so I asked, and the she answered (i think) that it means "Cat food". But what confused me was the way she answered:

> Katzenfutter **halt.**

What did she mean writing it like that? What is the purpose of "halt"? Is it a slang way of saying something else?

Comment: It's the same meaning like _Katzenfutter **eben**_.

Comment: So the meaning would not change at all, without that word?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Es ist und bleibt Katzenfutter, _eben_ oder _halt_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Warum antwortest du eigentlich immer in Kommentaren?

Comment: @David Weil ich der Meinung bin, dass sich eine Atwort auf so eine Frage nicht lohnt, wenn ich ein Close Vote abgegeben habe. Und es ist nicht _immer_, manchmal schreibe ich auch eine Antwort.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Warum lohnt sich dann der Kommentar?

Comment: @David Um dem OP auf die Sprünge zu helfen, darum. Ich bin ja kein Unmensch ;-).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Der Kommentar soll doch der Verbesserung der Frage dienen und die Antwort als Antwort? Und was ist, wenn du dich mit einem deiner Kommentare irren solltest? Im schlimmsten Fall: Frage geschlossen, falscher Kommentar bleibt für immer. Also mich überzeugt in Bezug auf dieses Thema https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment.

Comment: Different language and therefor no duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pampe** ist das, was man heutzutage gemeinhin einen *Smoothie* nennt. Zusammengequirltes Zeug, dem man nicht mehr ansieht, was darin an ekligen Resten versteckt wurde. Handelsname *Soylent Green*. [Oder auch wie hier.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4Z51nANbbg&t=2m12s)

Der Modalpartikel *halt* kann verwendet werden, um ein **Schulterzucken** zu signalisieren. Andere Sprachen brauchen dafür Emojis.

Comment: Thanks! The "emoji" answer help me understand very well what it means :)

Comment: +1 für *Soylent Green*